# Left - Middle - Right content with reponsive elements

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

The contents mush be responsive so that they don't jumble up on each other
HTML :

```
<div id="ContentPanel1">
  <div id="ContentLeft1">  Mars (Distance: 100) </div>
  <div id="ContentMiddle1"> Middle </div>
  <div id="ContentRight1"> Right </div> 
</div>
```

CSS :

```
#ContentPanel1 {
    text-align:center
}
#ContentLeft1 {
    background:Yellow;
    float: left;
    width: 80px;
}
#ContentMiddle1 {
    background:Orange;
    float: left;
    width: calc(100% - 160px);
}
#ContentRight1 {
    background:Blue;
    float: right;
    width: 80px;
}
```

I know most of the answers are already in the stackoverflow but I don't think any of them is responsive design, they all are hard coded. That's why I as asking this question again...

Comment: Why not use flex for this?

Comment: Use flexbox or grid with mediaqueries.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, this is easily achieved using `display: flex`. If you set a `min-width` or a `width` for each element, and use `flex-wrap: wrap`, the elements will automatically be wrapped to a next line. I think this qualifies what you mean with "not jumble up on each other", but correct me if I'm wrong.

Your code would become something like this (you can run the snippet and resize your browser window to test responsiveness):

```css
#ContentPanel1 {
    text-align:center;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#ContentLeft1 {
    background:Yellow;
    width: 80px;
}
#ContentMiddle1 {
    background:Orange;
    width: calc(100% - 160px);
    min-width: 200px;
}
#ContentRight1 {
    background:Blue;
    width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div id="ContentPanel1">
  <div id="ContentLeft1">  Mars (Distance: 100) </div>
  <div id="ContentMiddle1"> Middle </div>
  <div id="ContentRight1"> Right </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add the following to each of the classes in your css     width:33.3%' box-sizing:border-size;   NOTE: make your  width is a result of the dividing 100% by the number of divs you want on each line.